# What is the 70s/80s rock song that ends with this extended Mixolydian-based vamp?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

I heard this on a Classic Rock radio station recently and haven't been able to track it down for the last few weeks.

A single-voice rendition of the vamp is available [here](https://voca.ro/1gQNCAkqaRtH).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Layla - Derek and the Dominoes